# How can I implement ssr on vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router, server-side-rendering

I search on google with keyword ssr vuetify and I find this github : https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack-ssr

I try to implement it. I clone the project and save it in the webpack-ssr folder

Then I run it and there exist error like this :

[image]

So there exist error : `Missing required argument <app-name>.`

How can I solve this error? I want to implement ssr in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it wants you to pass the app name as an extra argument:

`vue init vuetifyjs/webpack-ssr my-app`

Also there appears to be a warning that you need `@vue/cli-init` package. So may want to install that first too:

`npm install @vue/cli-init --save-dev`

Comment: Great. It works. I just need to run this : `vue init vuetifyjs/webpack-ssr my-app`. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524595/how-can-i-implement-server-side-rendering-ssr-on-the-vuetify-project-that-is-1